# How to assign the same value for a specific column to all rows in a Window Partition

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, window-functions

I have a Dataframe with names and scores by year as follows:

```
val originalDF = Seq(
     |     (1, "Arthur", 5, "2010"),
     |     (2, "Arthur", 15, "2012"),
     |     (3, "Arthur", 10, "2017"),
     |     (4, "Trevor", 30, "2014"),
     |     (5, "Trevor", 12, "2015"),
     |     (6, "Franklin", 15, "2016"),
     |     (7, "Franklin", 20, "2018")
     |   ).toDF("id", "user", "score", "year")
```

Which returns:

```
+---+--------+-----+----+
| id|    user|score|year|
+---+--------+-----+----+
|  1|  Arthur|    5|2010|
|  2|  Arthur|   15|2012|
|  3|  Arthur|   10|2017|
|  4|  Trevor|   30|2014|
|  5|  Trevor|   12|2015|
|  6|Franklin|   15|2016|
|  7|Franklin|   20|2018|
+---+--------+-----+----+
```

What I want is to keep for each row `id`, `user` and `score`, but the year column should display the `best_year` for the `user`, based on his highest historical score. That would be:

```
+---+--------+-----+---------+
| id|    name|score|best_year|
+---+--------+-----+---------+
|  1|  Arthur|    5|     2012|
|  2|  Arthur|   15|     2012|
|  3|  Arthur|   10|     2012|
|  4|  Trevor|   30|     2014|
|  5|  Trevor|   12|     2014|
|  6|Franklin|   15|     2018|
|  7|Franklin|   20|     2018|
+---+--------+-----+---------+
```

The method I came up so far to solve this problem requires to generate a new DataFrame with the max score grouped by user, to finally join that new DataFrame with the original one:

```
val wind = Window.partitionBy("user").orderBy(col("score").desc)

val bestScores = originalDF.withColumn("rank", row_number over wind).where($"rank" === 1)    
     
val solution = originalDF.alias("o").join(bestScores.alias("b"), $"o.user" === $"b.user").select($"o.id", $"o.user", $"o.score", $"b.year")
```

My question: is it possible to achieve the same with less steps? Maybe only using window functions but without the additional join?

Answer (score 1):

You can find the year according to the maximum score using a max window function for a struct:

```
val df2 = originalDF.withColumn(
    "year", 
    max(struct(col("score"),col("year"))).over(Window.partitionBy("user"))("year")
)

df2.show
+---+--------+-----+----+
| id|    user|score|year|
+---+--------+-----+----+
|  1|  Arthur|    5|2012|
|  2|  Arthur|   15|2012|
|  3|  Arthur|   10|2012|
|  4|  Trevor|   30|2014|
|  5|  Trevor|   12|2014|
|  6|Franklin|   15|2018|
|  7|Franklin|   20|2018|
+---+--------+-----+----+
```